# jdk7 32 bit windows version to download

Tags: java, windows-7, java-7

I am just trying to download `JDK 7`, `32-bit` version for `windows 7`. The system requirement for the `JDK` on `Oracle` says it supports a `32-bit` version, but it is not listed on the download page. How can I download the `32-bit` version?

Comment: How is this a useful question for anybody?
Just querying for the same in a search engine would yield the solution.

Comment: @nikhil it's more useful now that JDK 7 is now an archived download ;-)

Comment: @andyb you got me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-se-jdk-7-download-432154.html) and download the `Windows x86` version with filename `jdk-7-windows-i586.exe`.

Comment: So is that what we should install if we have windows 7 64-bit and we want a JVM 32-bit ?

Comment: @Tarik Well, you want the version that says `Windows x86` but I'd assume  you'd want JDK 8 rather than 7: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: yes that's right and thanks for the help:) actually it's because i want to use Jboss tools in eclipse and its not yet compatible with 64-bit JVM

Comment: The linked webpage doesn't offer download link any more. See @andyb post for link to jdk7 archive download webpage.

Answer (score 8):

As detailed in the [Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html#Java6-end-public-updates)

> After April 2015, Oracle will no longer post updates of Java SE 7 to its public download sites. Existing Java SE 7 downloads already posted as of April 2015 will remain accessible in the Java Archive

Check the [Java SE 7 Archive Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) page. The last release was **update 80**, therefore the 32-bit filename to download is `jdk-7u80-windows-i586.exe` (64-bit is named `jdk-7u80-windows-x64.exe`.

Old Java downloads also require a sign on to an Oracle account now :-( however with some [crafty cookie creating](https://ivan-site.com/2012/05/download-oracle-java-jre-jdk-using-a-script/) one can use `wget` to grab the file without signing in.

```
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-windows-i586.exe"
```

Comment: Although this did prompt me to rewrite the answer for 2017

Comment: The archive page seems to require an oracle login to download

Comment: @MatteoTassinari thanks for the comment. You are correct, it seems that Oracle changed something again. I started looking into a solution but haven't found anything that works yet :-( Stupid of Oracle to demand a login to download old versions

Answer (score 0):

Look for "Windows x86", it's the 32 bit version.