# How can I check if I am running 32bit or 64bit java in C#

Tags: java, c#

I am writing my first C# program and I want to check using C# code if I am running a 32 or 64 bit version of java ?

I tried this but when I add this code to my class I am not able to debug it

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
RegistryKey subKey = rk.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment");
string currentVerion = subKey.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
```

How can I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: If you're running only on Windows, you could try running a command prompt `java -version`

Comment: There could be more then one JRE installed.

Comment: how can I run java -version from C# code and getting the result

Comment: "I am not able to debug it" what does that mean?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "java -version");`

Comment: @Keews How I will get the result I mean in the form of a string? I want to get the java version and store it in a variable

Comment: When I run this code it just opens the command line nothing more

Comment: Why are you checking what version of Java you're running from C#? Like, is this intentional?

Comment: yes I need to load a dll based on my java version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear how you are going to identify which java.exe you are using - a single machine can have many installed. You may have a specific path, or you may need to either use the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, or search `PATH`, or do a combination of both and give priority to one or the other depending on your requirements.

Once you've got your path to `java.exe` you can use the technique from Kris Stanton on MSDN (which I will repeat here, but is currently linked at [MSDN > "Exploring pe file headers using managed code"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kstanton/archive/2004/03/31/105060.aspx)):

```
public enum MachineType
{
    Native = 0, I586 = 0x014c, Itanium = 0x0200, x64 = 0x8664
}
public static MachineType GetMachineType(string fileName)
{
    // dos header is 64 bytes
    // PE header address is 4 bytes
    const int PE_PTR_OFFSET = 60;
    const int MACHINE_OFFSET = 4;
    byte[] data = new byte[4096];
    using (Stream stm = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        stm.Read(data, 0, 4096);
    }
    int PE_HDR_ADDR = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, PE_PTR_OFFSET);
    int machineUint = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, PE_HDR_ADDR + MACHINE_OFFSET);
    return (MachineType)machineUint;
}
```

To find `java.exe` on the `%PATH%` variable, you can call `FindOnPath("java.exe")`:

```
public static String FindOnPath(string exeName)
{
    foreach (string test in (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH") ?? "").Split(';'))
    {
        string path = test.Trim();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(path) && File.Exists(path = Path.Combine(path, exeName)))
            return Path.GetFullPath(path);
    }
    return null;
}
```

On my machine, the following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String path = FindOnPath("java.exe");
    Console.WriteLine(path);
    Console.WriteLine(GetMachineType(path));
}
```

writes the following output:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
x64
```

Comment: I just need to get if my current java installation which is in use is 32bit or 64bit nothing more

Comment: @wearybands - that is exactly what this code does. First you find the path to the java.exe, then you interrogate the file to find out what it was compiled for.

Comment: What is this machine type used for ? I am running only windows

Comment: and instead of writing it on Console how can I store this in a string variable?

Comment: @wearybands - `i586` [is the 32bit install](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7075093/1945631), `x64` is just that. As for "*how do I store [anything] in a string variable*" - I am afraid that sounds like another question. I suggest you search SO for the answer, or ask a new question - SO is designed for one specific question per post.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through the registry. I knocked together a quick example for you:

```
private string GetJavaInstallationPath()
{
    string environmentPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentPath))
    {
       return environmentPath;
    }

    string javaKey = "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment\\";
    using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey rk = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(javaKey))
    {
        string currentVersion = rk.GetValue("CurrentVersion").ToString();
        using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = rk.OpenSubKey(currentVersion))
        {
            return key.GetValue("JavaHome").ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it, just do the following:

```
string installPath = GetJavaInstallationPath();
string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(installPath, "bin\\Java.exe");
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
{
    // We have a winner
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I`m use this code:

```
public static bool CheckJavaInstallation()
{
    try
    {
        //ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", " -version"); // Check that any Java installed
        //ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", "-d32 -version"); // Check that 32 bit Java installed
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", "-d64 -version"); // Check that 64 bit Java installed

        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process proc = new Process {StartInfo = procStartInfo};
        proc.Start();

        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit();
        return proc.ExitCode == 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```